# Accessing items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object returned from a $.ajax request. This is an example:

```
[{"id":"14","branchName":"Catcliffe","address1":"26 Main Street","address2":"","address3":null,"city":"Catcliffe","county":"South Yorkshire","postcode":"S60 5SR","country":"UK"}]
```

I am having a brain freeze on how to access items in the array, for example how would I set a variable to the 'branchName'...

This is the code I used to get the data:

```
$("#branchID").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
           url: "/admin/getBranchInfo.php?branchID=" + id,
           success: function(branch){
                       $("div#results").html(branch);
                    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the first element in the returned array using it's index, `[0]`, then you can grab the property you want from that, `.branchName`.

```
$("div#results").html(branch[0].branchName);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ3sy/)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I get 'undefined' in the console which is what baffled me in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

I just assumed that you are holding that object in a variable called xObj.

Try,

```
console.log(xObj[0].branchName)
```

But you should parse it before accessing the values since you have not mentioned the type,

```
var xObj = JSON.parse(branch);
console.log(xObj[0].branchName)
```

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry I was in a rush this morning and forgot to state it was a JSON object...this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `indexer`, to access the element of array. As array contains object you go to use dot `.` operator to access object properties like `branchName`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/83V5g/)**

```
$("div#results").html(branch[0].branchName);
```

Your code would be

```
$("#branchID").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/getBranchInfo.php?branchID=" + id,
        success: function (branch) {
            $("div#results").html(branch[0].branchName);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get the branchName property from the first (and only) item in the array:

```
$("div#results").html(branch[0].branchName);
```

Answer (score 0):

use object and using its property we can access it  branch[0].branchname

```
$("#branchID").change(function()
{
var id = $(this).val();
$.ajax(
{
url: "/admin/getBranchInfo.php?branchID=" + id,
success: function(branch)
{
var branchname= branch[0].branchname;
$("div#results").html(branch);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple objects you can loop the result using a for loop like the one given below:

```
for(var i in branch)
{
   var id = branch[i].id;
   var branchName = branch[i].branchName;
   //....
   //Iterate other objects as well
}
```